# SVN - How do I only get updated files from server but not commit any local changes I have made?

Tags: svn

I've made a bunch of local changes but I don't want to commit them. I want to get all the updated files from the server so I'm up-to-date with what everyone else has.

Is there a way to do this?

In my understanding, if I do 'svn update' it will also commit my changes I've made locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing an **svn update** is enough. Doing that no commit is done, so you're safe.
But may be you could get some conflicts between what you've changed and what others have changed.

In case of conflicts, you'll have to merge the changes. But until you do a commit, nothing will be sent to the server.